Can Adjusted Profit Margin be used to do a future projection
I know there is a difference between adjusted profit margin and standard/normal profit margin. However, if a company is reporting only their adjusted profit and also has declared publicly their goal to keep the adjusted profit margin at X%, will it be entirely wrong to use that value to make a forward prediction of what the profit might be if the revenue is also expected to increase by x% per year. (More or less making the non-cash expenses and non-cash gains unchanged/fixed).
For example:
If a company has 1,000 in revenue and their adjusted profit margin is 10%. Then the adjusted profit will be 100. Now if we also know that their expected increase in revenue is 20% for the next three years. How accurate would it be to assume that their profit will be ~ 172 in 3 years. (1000*(1+0.2)^3) * (0.1)
If not is there another way to tie the declared adjusted profit margin with something else in order to be able to make a forward looking prediction of what the company might profit in 3-5-10 years.
